# Java: how to read matrices with unknown size

Tags: java, input, system.in

I need to store the matrix into a[][] from standard input. (System.in)

How do I initialize a if the size is unknown

Please help, thanks

Comment: You can't. Use an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. Otherwise you will need to grow the array each time you need more space.

Comment: In addition to Sotirios suggestion: use `ArrayList`s or `LinkedList`s to receive the user input and, then, after everything was received, you will be able to instantiate the multidimensional array you want (a[][]), as you'll have its sizes.